# show some data in koha ILS authority normal view

Tags: perl

in opac-authoritiesdetail.pl 
i add

```
$template->param( "tag_781_z" => $record->subfield('781','z') );
```

and in opac-auth-detail.tt

```
[% IF( tag_781_z ) %]
    <span class="">
        <span class="label">Geographic Subdivision
        </span>
        [% tag_781_z %]
    </span> 
[% END %]
```

the result 
the first value only shown 
but I add 3 value

Comment: Please give more details. What do you mean by *"add 3 value"* ?

Comment: How to view the result of inserting a new Repeatable filed 780$z in normal view OPAC authority

Answer (score 0):

If field 780$z is repeatable you must add value this field to array.

Regards